# Rails: How do I call 'create' action in jQuery ( .js.erb )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4.1.1 
I was wondering, how do I call the 'create' action in  jQuery ( .js.erb )?
Please see below my jquery codes and my **user_controller.rb**, I would like to call the **user_controller.rb** create action in the jquery **if else** code.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :user
  root 'user#index'
end
```

**user_controller.rb**

```
class UserController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @users = User.all
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    redirect_to "/"
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
  end

end
```

**subscribe.js.erb**

```
$(function () {
  $("#subscribe").submit(function (event) {
    var input = $('.my-subscribe-message');
      if(!input.is(':empty')) {
        $('.my-subscribe-message').stop(true);
      }
      event.preventDefault();
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();

      var email = $("input#subscribe-email").val();

      if (email == "") {

        $(".my-subscribe-message").stop(true).html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> You must enter a valid e-mail address.');
        $("input#subscribe-email").focus();
      } 
      else if (!isValidEmailAddress( email )) {
        $(".my-subscribe-message").stop(true).html('<i class="fa fa-warning"></i> E-mail address is not valid.');
        $("input#subscribe-email").focus();            
      }
      else {
        $.ajax({

/* I would like to call the create action here */

          success: function () {
            $(".my-subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> We will be in touch soon!');
            $('input#subscribe-email').val('');
          }
        });
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Please add your `routes.rb` specifically with regards to `user`

Comment: ok I have added the routes.rb

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give this a punt:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/users",
  data: { user: { email: "blah@blah.com" } },
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, it looks like it doesn't execute the codes cos the message didn't appear.

Comment: @laman - what do you mean 'it doesn't execute the codes cos the message didn't appear' ?

Comment: the message `$(".my-subscribe-message").html('<i class="fa fa-check"></i> We will be in touch soon!')` didn't appear when I add `type: "POST",
  url: "/users",
  data: { user: { email: "blah@blah.com" } },`